# KQL query | summarize arg_max

Tags: sql, azure, azure-functions, kql, argmax

I have developed a powershell script that checkes the Status of Application Pool in IIS and gives me an output like this in Azure Function App:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Yuv.png)

the function app should run every two hours and I am trying to make a kql query to filter the logs and show me only the last status of each Application pool on each Server as follow:

```
traces
| where message contains "AppNAme:"
| parse message with * "OUTPUT: ResourceGroupName:" ResourceGroupName "VmName:" VmName "AppNAme: " AppName "Status: " Status
| where AppName !contains "SharePoint Web Services Root" and VmName !contains "PHA02"
| extend flag = iif(Status == "Started", 1, 0)
| summarize arg_max(strcat(timestamp,flag), *) by itemType
| project timestamp, ResourceGroupName, VmName, AppName, Status
```

at this line | summarize arg_max(strcat(timestamp,flag), *) by itemType
my aim is to filter the logs and show the latest status of each Application pool. but this code brings me the latest application pool of last server. I need the latest status of each application pool on each server.

could someone might help me.
I appreciate it a lot.

I tried this

```
traces
| where message contains "AppNAme:"
| parse message with * "OUTPUT: ResourceGroupName:" ResourceGroupName "VmName:" VmName "AppNAme: " AppName "Status: " Status
| where AppName !contains "SharePoint Web Services Root" and VmName !contains "PHA02"
| extend flag = iif(Status == "Started", 1, 0)
| summarize arg_max(strcat(timestamp,flag), *) by itemType
| project timestamp, ResourceGroupName, VmName, AppName, Status
```

at this line | summarize arg_max(strcat(timestamp,flag), *) by itemType
my aim is to filter the logs and show the latest status of each Application pool. but this code brings me the latest application pool of last server. I need the latest status of each application pool on each server.

Answer (score 0):

Try a summarization by AppName and VmName:

```
traces
| where message contains "AppNAme:"
| parse message with * "OUTPUT: ResourceGroupName:" ResourceGroupName "VmName:" VmName "AppNAme: " AppName "Status: " Status
| where AppName !contains "SharePoint Web Services Root" and VmName !contains "PHA02"
| extend flag = iif(Status == "Started", 1, 0)
| summarize arg_max(timestamp, *) by VmName, AppName
| project timestamp, ResourceGroupName, VmName, AppName, Status
```